# 'apt-get clean' returns error in Ubuntu 20.04 LST with WSL2

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

`apt-get clean`

returns errors

E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)

when run on ubuntu 20.04 LTS in wsl-2 on Windows

Tried various solutions on internet but nothing worked

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run the command with sudo:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```